# Directory in intel sourcechecker constantly updates

Tags: linux, compilation, intel

We have an intel compiler installed. Its location is something like:

```
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_<version info>/
```

The compilers work great--no issues with that. The problem I'm seeing is that there are two directories in particular that update every in a while. It's just their timestamp; nothing else:

```
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_<version info>/bin/sourcechecker/lib/ia32/pinruntime/glibc
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_<version info>/bin/sourcechecker/lib/intel64/pinruntime/glibc
```

The contents of these directories are a handful of .so files. For example, in the intel64/pinruntime/glibc one:

```
ld-2.3.4.so
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libc-2.3.4.so
libc.so.6
<etc.>
```

These files don't change, and haven't changed since 2012. Their containing folder (glibc) does, however.

This proves troublesome for one of our file integrity checks, which reports these directories as errors. I've scoured Stackoverflow and the Intel forums, but the closest issues I can find have to do with RPM repackaging (which is not my issue).

Why are the timestamps on these directories updating?